# Failing to run Sencha app at runtime error

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Everytime I run the sencha app it's giving below error...

I upgraded the app to the latest version, that did not fix the issue either.

I have sencha 6.6 on my computer and I am not entirely sure what version is this Sencha app written in... Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason on this issue?

```
localhost/:7 GET http://localhost:1841/resources/lib/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.js:1595 GET http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1540324633621 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
evaluateLoadElement @ bootstrap.js:1595
loadElement @ bootstrap.js:1509
load @ bootstrap.js:1563
loadEntries @ bootstrap.js:1139
processRequest @ bootstrap.js:724
load @ bootstrap.js:746
onCachedAssetsReady @ bootstrap.js:2264
load @ bootstrap.js:2228
setManifest @ bootstrap.js:2169
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:2141
readyStateChange @ bootstrap.js:854
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ VM330:1
fetch @ bootstrap.js:868
run @ bootstrap.js:2140
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.js:2698
Component.js?_dc=1540324633620:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Component.js?_dc=1540324633620:1
(anonymous) @ Component.js?_dc=1540324633620:1
ButtonGroup.js?_dc=1540324633620:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at ButtonGroup.js?_dc=1540324633620:1
(anonymous) @ ButtonGroup.js?_dc=1540324633620:1
HtmlEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at HtmlEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ HtmlEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
RowEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at RowEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ RowEditor.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Dock.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Dock.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Dock.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Separator.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Separator.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Separator.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Panel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Panel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Panel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Table.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Table.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Table.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Toolbar.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Toolbar.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Toolbar.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Component.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Component.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Component.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Checkbox.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Checkbox.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Checkbox.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Check.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Check.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Check.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Column.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Column.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Column.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ RowNumberer.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
RowExpander.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at RowExpander.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ RowExpander.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
TreeItem.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at TreeItem.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ TreeItem.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Item.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Item.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Item.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Menu.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Date.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Date.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Date.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Month.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Splitter.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
CheckboxModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at CheckboxModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ CheckboxModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
SpreadsheetModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at SpreadsheetModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ SpreadsheetModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Paging.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
MainController.js?_dc=1540324633621:7 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at MainController.js?_dc=1540324633621:7
(anonymous) @ MainController.js?_dc=1540324633621:7
MainModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at MainModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
(anonymous) @ MainModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
Global.js?_dc=1540324633621:2 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Global.js?_dc=1540324633621:2
(anonymous) @ Global.js?_dc=1540324633621:2
ChildSessionForm.js?_dc=1540324633621:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at ChildSessionForm.js?_dc=1540324633621:21
(anonymous) @ ChildSessionForm.js?_dc=1540324633621:21
LiveDetailController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at LiveDetailController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ LiveDetailController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Base.js?_dc=1540324633621:4 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Base.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
(anonymous) @ Base.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
Contract.js?_dc=1540324633621:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at Contract.js?_dc=1540324633621:25
(anonymous) @ Contract.js?_dc=1540324633621:25
LiveDetailModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at LiveDetailModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
(anonymous) @ LiveDetailModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
Trade.js?_dc=1540324633621:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at Trade.js?_dc=1540324633621:45
(anonymous) @ Trade.js?_dc=1540324633621:45
LiveDetail.js?_dc=1540324633621:95 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.create is not a function
    at LiveDetail.js?_dc=1540324633621:95
(anonymous) @ LiveDetail.js?_dc=1540324633621:95
ReportController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at ReportController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ ReportController.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
ContractReport.js?_dc=1540324633621:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at ContractReport.js?_dc=1540324633621:16
(anonymous) @ ContractReport.js?_dc=1540324633621:16
ReportModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at ReportModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:13
(anonymous) @ ReportModel.js?_dc=1540324633621:13
Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:37 Uncaught ReferenceError: OffsetApp is not defined
    at Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:37
(anonymous) @ Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:37
Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Report.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Main.js?_dc=1540324633621:1 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Main.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
(anonymous) @ Main.js?_dc=1540324633621:1
Root.js?_dc=1540324633621:4 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Root.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
(anonymous) @ Root.js?_dc=1540324633621:4
Application.js?_dc=1540324633621:6 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.define is not a function
    at Application.js?_dc=1540324633621:6
(anonymous) @ Application.js?_dc=1540324633621:6
app.js?_dc=1540324633621:6 Uncaught TypeError: Ext.application is not a function
    at app.js?_dc=1540324633621:6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parts of your log are as follows:

`ext-all-rtl-debug.js ... 404 (Not Found)`

ext-all-rtl-debug.js is the file that contains the basic framework as packed together by Sencha for you. And if that cannot be loaded because [error 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), then of course your app won't load.

As to why, you will have to check whether the file is misisng from the ext/build  directory, or if it is in the directory, then why the server is not delivering it.

Answer (score 0):

Along with a great tip of @Alexander, I found out that build directory was missing, so once I moved that from an another sencha app to this under "ext" folder, app loaded fine.

Thank you @Alexander!